# Run-time error in a jdbc program,"Before start of result set"

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to write a JDBC program for following situation

> the client wants an automated system that ask for user authentication. After successful login a menu appears offering an option to view salary calculated. In this option, ask for user to enter number of days then it calculates salary as per the da rules.

In this problem i have a created a database where each employee has its own Unique id and password. Here is my employee table.

> [image]

so what i done :i created a main class file and separate threads for every option in menu but I am getting problem only in the following one . Though I have created my own user defined exception ,which supposed to run in case null result set . but its seems its not executing at all.
Whenever I try to execute this thread "Cal_sal" it gives following error.

> [image]

Here is my Code :

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cal_sal implements Runnable{
    private final int emp_id;
    private final String password;
    public Cal_sal(int emp_id, String password) {
        this.emp_id=emp_id;
        this.password=password;
    }
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/assignment1&2","root","4556");
            PreparedStatement stmt= con.prepareStatement("select * from employee where emp_id=? and pass=?");
            stmt.setInt(1,emp_id);
            stmt.setString(2,password);
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
            if(rs==null) {
                throw new error("Data not found, as per provided employee id and password.");
            }
            else
            {
                String category = rs.getString(3);
                int days;
                double Tsal,DA,bsal= rs.getInt(4);
                System.out.println("Enter number of days");
                days=input.nextInt();
                DA = (days / 30) * bsal;
                switch (category)
                {
                    case "staff" -> {
                        Tsal = (20 / 100) * DA;
                        System.out.println("Total Salary for " + days + " is " + Tsal);
                    }
                    case "engineer" -> {
                        Tsal = (15 / 100) * DA;
                        System.out.println("Total Salary for " + days + " is " + Tsal);
                    }
                    case "manager" -> {
                        Tsal = (10 / 100) * DA;
                        System.out.println("Total Salary for " + days + " is " + Tsal);
                    }
                    default -> throw new error("Unknown Error Contact admin");
                }
            }
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException | error | ClassNotFoundException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

When i give wrong id or password ,instead of providing throwing user defined exception `error` its says `Illegal operation on empty result set.`
please help me to solve this error.

Comment: You must read the next() from the resultset before picking out the values.

Comment: `PreparedStatement.executeQuery()` does not return `null`. Where did you get that idea? And the error occurs regardless of whether you supplied the correct name and password. You *must* call `ResultSet.next()` before retrieving any data from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to use the result of rs.next() :

```
if (!rs.next()) {
       throw new error("Data not found, as per provided employee id and password.");
}
```

If rs.next() returns false, this means the query returned no rows.

Comment: And only if it doesn't is it legal to retrieve cell values from it.